Method of moments: uncertainty of estimated parameter
In some physics paper, it is needed to find best estimate to parameter P for p.d.f. of the measured physical quantity $\cos\theta$ :
$$
\frac{dN}{d\cos\theta} = \frac{1+P\cos\theta}{2}
$$
Of course, it may be estimated as $\hat{P} = 3\langle\cos\theta\rangle$, where $\langle \dots \rangle$ is the mean value.
But the detector biased the measured distribution with unknown acceptance function $A(\cos\theta)$ that is symmetric in $\cos \theta$, hence the acceptance bias can be taken into account using the formula shown in the paper:
$$
\hat{P} \pm \Delta(\hat{P}) = \frac{\langle \cos\theta \rangle}{\langle \cos^2 \theta \rangle} \pm \frac{1}{\sqrt{N}} \frac{\left[\langle \cos^2 \theta (1 - P \cos \theta )^2 \rangle \right]^{1/2}}{\langle \cos^2 \theta \rangle} ,
$$
where $N$ is the number of measurements.
As for $P$ value, this formula is easy to proof, using $A(\cos\theta)$ is symmetric gives:
$$
E[\langle \cos\theta \rangle] = \frac{1}{2} \int A(\cos\theta)\cos^2\theta d(\cos\theta),
E[\langle \cos^2\theta \rangle] = \frac{P}{2} \int A(\cos\theta)\cos^2\theta d(\cos\theta)
$$
$$
\Rightarrow \hat{P} = \frac{\langle \cos\theta \rangle}{\langle \cos^2 \theta \rangle}.
$$
How to prove the formula for uncertainty, which takes into account the correlation
between $\langle\cos\theta\rangle$ and $\langle\cos^2\theta\rangle$?
I hardly can find any resource/book describing 'uncertainty' (whatever it may mean) or confidence intervals in the method of moments.
